# Core data backed UITableView giving error when deleting cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, magicalrecord

I've got a UITableView backed by an array of Core Data objects, made by appending two arrays of Core Data objects named folders and notes. Whenever I try to delete a row from the table view, it throws:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

Here's the code to delete (in my UITableViewCell subclass):

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
[object MR_deleteInContext:context];
[context MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
[tableViewController loadData];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
```

Note: the MR_ methods are [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) methods, they do what they say.

Here's the loadData method in the UITableViewController (basically refetches the array):

```
NSPredicate *textParentFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parent == %@", self.parent];
self.notes = [Note MR_findAllWithPredicate:textParentFilter];
NSPredicate *folderParentFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parentFolder == %@", self.parent];
self.folders = [Folder MR_findAllWithPredicate:folderParentFilter];
```

Also:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.notes count] + [self.folders count];
}
```

I can see why I'm getting an exception: I'm deleting the row in loadData and then the numberOfRowsInSection is out of sync from the tableview and the Core Data store. However, if I replace deleteRowsAtIndexPaths with [tableView reloadData], it deletes just fine (but there's no animation). I've tried beginUpdates and endUpdates, switching the order in which things are deleted, to no avail.

Comment: Your problem is that `self.notes.count + self.folders.count` == 2, both before and after you tell the table view that you deleted something.   So either you didn't actually delete anything from your data model, or you deleted and then added something.

Comment: BTW, in response to trying multiple orders the correct order is: (1) delete the item from the data source, (2) call `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:`.  Do not call `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:` until `self.notes.count + self.folders.count` will == 1.

Comment: Testing on a single note: before loadData `NSArray *t = [tableController.folders arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:tableController.notes];` had one object, after it had 0 (which I gather to be correct). It throws `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 0 from section 0 which only contains 0 rows before the update'`

Comment: @Januzellij what `[tableViewController loadData];` does?

Comment: I explained it in my question

Comment: It seems like you might have a race condition.  Is all of your delete work done on the main thread?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes.

Comment: I strongly urge you to move away from MR_contextForCurrentThread. It will lead to random, thread based crashes over time. The recommended pattern is similar, but more manual. Create a new context for your thread, and dispose of it when you're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it! Or rather, NSFetchedResultsController fixed it. I've implemented

`- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath`

in my view controller to `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:`. My delete method is now just

`NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
[object MR_deleteInContext:context];
[context MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];`

(thanks for the advice about MR_contextForCurrentThread).

Here's loadData:

`NSManagedObjectContext *c = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
NSPredicate *textParentFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parent == %@", self.parent];
self.notes = [Note MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"text" ascending:YES withPredicate:textParentFilter groupBy:nil delegate:self inContext:c];
NSPredicate *folderParentFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parentFolder == %@", self.parent];
self.folders = [Folder MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"title" ascending:YES withPredicate:folderParentFilter groupBy:nil delegate:self inContext:c];`

And - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section:

`if ([self.notes.sections count] + [self.folders.sections count] > 0) {
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> notesSectionInfo = [self.notes.sections objectAtIndex:section];
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> foldersSectionInfo = [self.folders.sections objectAtIndex:section];
        return [notesSectionInfo numberOfObjects] + [foldersSectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    } else
        return 0;`

Answer (score 3):

When working with UITableViews and Core Data, it is important that the objects in your storage (e.g., your notes and folders arrays) match the UITableView delegate/datasource calls at all times. When you start animating cells for addition, deletion and updating, you encounter synchronisation issues where occasionally, the values don't align. A good example is when you have to perform multiple cell additions/deletions in succession while showing or revealing a section of a table. If you use [tableView reloadData], you enforce synchronisation but won't be able to animate the cells.

`NSFetchedResultsController` can be used to synchronise multiple cell additions/deletions with animations. It will require a bit of rewiring on your end, but not as much as you'd think. With this, you can control animation styles, even bulk modify cells while keeping your table intact. NSFetchedResultsController will listen to changes in Core Data based on a predicate, and reflect these changes in the tableview. This means you can have multiple tableviews respond with their own NSFetchedResultsController without having to notify them, and everything will stay synchronised.

A good place to find skeleton code is to set up a new Core Data project in XCode. Methods that you'll need to add to your code (found in MasterViewController.m):

```
// this references your controller that listens to Core Data and communicates with the tableview
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController 

// delegate methods:
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller;
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
       atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type;
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
   atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
  newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath;
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller;
```

Your tableview will then need to consult the NSFetchedController instance for it's delegate/datasource methods. For example:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

If you're feeling advanced enough, there's a great tutorial that shows how you can queue cells additions/deletions for improved performance:

http://www.fruitstandsoftware.com/blog/2013/02/uitableview-and-nsfetchedresultscontroller-updates-done-right/

`NSFetchedResultsController` is one of those things that you don't really hear about in a basic Core Data tutorial, but it proves to be a real asset when doing table animations and handling large amounts of data (through caching).

Comment: A couple of people have recommended NAFetchedResultsController, and I'm currently refactoring to use it. Thanks for the extra info!

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code whenever a user slides a cell to delete it:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        if (tableView == self.tableView)
        {
           NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
           Entry *e = self.entries[row];

           [self.entries removeObjectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

           [e MR_deleteEntity];
           [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }
}
```

In your case you first need to figure out if 'row' corresponds to a `Note` or a `Folder`, but the idea is the same.

Comment: That's the weird thing. When I just delete the entity from the Core Data store and the array, then reloadData, it works fine. It's only when I use deleteRowsAtIndexPaths that I get problems.

Comment: So why do you use `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` ?

Comment: This may sound petty, but I'd like the animation when it deletes

Comment: Heh :)  Maybe this solution may help you: http://keithposehn.net/post/12164756946/ios-uitableview-delete-row-w-coredata-animation.  I may actually use that myself as well!

Comment: So I would have to switch to NSFetchedResultsController?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I think you can get the `NSFetchedResultsController` through `MagicalRecord`, and then you set your viewController as it's delegate.